# Will there be landing cards in the UK after Brexit occurs?

Tags: uk, eu-citizens, brexit

As of today, both in case of a no-deal, a yes-deal, or a delayed Brexit, will EU citizens be required upon entering the UK after 29 March 2019 to fill in a landing card? If yes, how does it look like?

Comment: Why wouldn’t it look like the one that already exists? There are lots of examples online, they seem to be pretty generic and suitable for post-Brexit use eg https://goo.gl/images/NYCf6c

Comment: It's not likely. The most likely scenario is you continue going through the ePassport gates as you currently do now. The UK is even expanding the use of the gates to various non-EU nationals this year.

Comment: Nominated to be reopened as landing cards have now been scrapped for everyone coming to the UK, therefore a solid answer can be used.

Answer (score 9):

According to the [UK Border Force](https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/at-border-control):

> **You no longer have to fill in a landing card.** Your passport (and visa if you have one) will be checked at border control. You’ll usually be asked why you’re coming to the UK.

Therefore the question is pretty much moot, as no one will have to fill out landing cards anymore as of 2019, regardless of what happens during the Brexit process.

Comment: I can confirm, i just came back from there and there were no landing cards whatsoever for anyone.

Answer (score 7):

I'm afraid that this falls into the category of "we don't know at the present."  If free movement persists under the Immigration (EEA) Regulations 2016 or successor legislation, the landing cards will not be required.  But the timing of the repeal of that legislation appears uncertain in the event of a no-deal departure.  If there is a deal, the timing will depend on the precise details of the deal, which are as yet indeterminate.  The prospect of a delay, of course, makes the already uncertain timing even less certain.

Once the EEA regulations are repealed, EU-citizen visitors are likely to be required to fill out the landing card, but the cards are also likely to be scrapped entirely (perhaps only after immigration authorities have had a chance to catch their breath in the wake of departure from the EU).  In August 2017, the Home Office announced plans to stop using the cards, expecting to implement those plans by the autumn of 2017, but this never happened.

Comment: In 2017, the UK Govt was looking at scrapping Landing Cards for all non-EU travelers. There is an article (on line) in the Times dated 8 Aug 1017. The plan at that time was to scrap them from Oct.'17 but there were concerns regarding border security.

Comment: @canonacer but I could find no indication that the plan was definitively abandoned because of those concerns.  Rather, it appears simply to have fallen off the agenda.  There's nothing to suggest that they won't bring it up again once they have time to do so in a couple of years.

Comment: phoog, sorry I messed up my edit and had meant to include something along your lines of "pending" or "gone quiet".